# Leaflet custom marker GeoJSON

Tags: leaflet, geojson

I want to change marker from blue default to my own design. But I linked JSON external and I don't know what I have to change in code.

`var featuresLayer = new L.GeoJSON(data, {
            style: function(feature) {
                return {color: feature.properties.color };
            },
            onEachFeature: function(feature, marker) {
                marker.bindPopup( "<b>Hello world!</b><br>ID vzorku    "+feature.properties.catalogNumber +
        "</br> nadm vyska  "+feature.properties.elevation+
        "<br>I am a popup."+feature.properties.tavg1  );
            }
        });`

Answer (score 2):

The formal [leaflet marker/Json example](http://leafletjs.com/examples/geojson/) is a good way to start.
Basically in order to load points as layers you should use `pointToLayer`

```
L.geoJSON(someGeojsonFeature, {
    pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
        return L.circleMarker(latlng, geojsonMarkerOptions); // The basic style
    }
}).addTo(map);
```

If all of your feature are in a layerGroup, you can change the layerGroup style with :

```
layerGroup.setStyle(styleMarkerByAttr); // Define a function, check the attr you need and style the marker accordingly.
```

In the style function you can reference your color attr - and set the icon/marker color respectively.

Further reading : [setIcon in the leaflet doc](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.1.0.html#marker-seticon)

Answer (score 1):

I think Font Awesome or CircleMarkers are the two easiest methods.

Font Awesome example:
http://zevross.com/blog/2014/10/28/tips-for-creating-leafleft-js-maps/

Or CircleMarkers example. http://www.gistechsolutions.com/leaflet/DEMO/baseball/Baseball.html

The Leaflet JS page also shows using icons as a demo.